# How much current and voltage could a betavoltaic device produce

Tags: electric-circuits

I would like to understand the amounts of energy a [betavoltaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betavoltaic_device) device could produce.

Let's say I put a convenient amount of isotope (1 kg of radium, or some other convenient isotope) suspended in a  metal box 1 meter on all  sides. The box is surrounded by an insulator, and then another metal box around that --  so we have a capacitor.

The articles say that the current is too small to be technologically useful and the voltage too high.  Does the current not depend on the size of the collector plates (6 sides, 1 m$^2$ for  each side)  and the amount of isotope?

Given this configuration,  how much current and what voltage should we expect?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to understand the amounts of energy a betavoltaic device could produce.

The amount of energy is limited at most to be equal to the energy from the decay. For 1 kg of Radium 226 the activity is 3.7 10^13 Bq. Since each decay is 4.9 MeV that is a total of 1.8 10^14 MeV/s = 29 W. This is assuming a perfect collector with 100% efficiency, and it is also assuming that this is the only decay mode present.

In comparison a lithium ion battery is about 300 W for a 1 kg battery pack.

> Let's say I put a convenient amount of isotope (1 kg of radium, or some other convenient isotope) suspended in a metal box 1 meter on all sides. The box is surrounded by an insulator, and then another metal box around that -- so we have a capacitor.

This is not a practical configuration. Alpha particles have very little penetration, so having a 1 kg box of isotope would prevent almost all of the alpha particles from escaping. You would get almost no energy. A far better approach would be to sandwich very thin layers of the emitter and absorber. That is the approach taken for the current best designs of betavoltaics, although they use a beta emitter instead of an alpha emitter.

However, regardless of the arrangement, the starting physical current and voltage is driven by the decay itself. Since an alpha particle has two protons that corresponds to a voltage of 4.9 MeV/2e or 2.45 MV. You can use various electronic methods to step down the voltage and step up the current, but that is what you fundamentally start with regardless of the configuration of the rest of your circuit.